# django REST new and id_name confusion

Tags: django, rest

I have this urls

```
/post/new
/post/1
/post/2/edit
```

but, with this in some case `new` is catched as a post id,

what is a correct url names ?

#### EDIT

When I use `HttpResponseRedirect('/post/new')` is catched as id

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see your urls.py file to be sure, but I'd imagine the regex you're using to pickup the post id is too loose and is picking up alphabetical characters as well.

The following urls should work:

```
url(r'^/post/new$', new_post_view)
url(r'^/post/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$', post_view)
url(r'^/post/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/edit$', edit_post_view)
```

If that doesn't solve your issue post your urlconf and I'll take another look.

Comment: I have some similar, but when I use `HttpResponseRedirect('/post/new')` is catched as id

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant urls from your urls.py file for me to be able to help any further, I haven't enough information to give you a complete answer without seeing it.